# How to change the input font size in TextField of Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to change the input font size in TextField of Android Jetpack Compose because it's very small now. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWy36.png)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Update:

I don't recall if the parameter was originally present when I originally answered, but there is a `fontSize` parameter on both the M2 and M3 `Text` composable that you can set directly and still have it respect the theme (think of it as a one off override)

---

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#TextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material.TextFieldColors)), there is a parameter `textStyle` that takes [`TextStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle) that allows you to set font size via `fontSize`.

You can do the following and it will set the font size to 28 sp

```
   TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {}, textStyle = TextStyle.Default.copy(fontSize = 28.sp))
```

note: if you want to ensure that your themed style still applies and you're just modifying the size of it, use `LocalTextStyle.current.merge(TextStyle(fontSize = 28.sp))` or `LocalTextStyle.current.copy(fontSize = 28.sp)` instead of `TextStyle.Default.copy(fontSize = 28.sp)`

Comment: Don't use `TextStyle.Default.copy()`. Instead use `LocalTextStyle.current.copy()`. LocalTextStyle.current respects your theme typography.

Comment: That's not totally necessary. Checking out the source code for `TextStyle.Default` you'll see that (at least for Android) the default text style doesn't really set anything, and since the passed style is merged with the LocalTextStyle by the TextField composable in a way that overwrites anything not provided by the passed style with the theme's style. Also, rather than using `copy`, using `merge` is apparently the more appropriate way of setting a single parameter for a single instance as it doesn't make extra allocations.

Comment: try it out by setting a type face font. If you use TextStyle.Default, it doesn't use the typeface which I mentioned in Theme. When I used LocalTextStyle.current, then it worked. You can see the default textStyle set in TextField is LocalTextStyle.current

Answer (score 5):

Now it is done using

```
TextField(textStyle = androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle(
                fontSize = fontSize,
                fontFamily = fontFamily
            ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField(
    value = "", 
    onValueChange = {}, 
    textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(fontSize = 28.sp)
)
```

Use this. This will follow your theme's typography.