# fontSize and textHeight don't work how do i fix this?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, font-size

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnYFH.png) fontSize and TextHeight look red and say unresolved reference but it doesn't tell me which package I have to import to use them on android studio. I am a beginner so I don't know how to fix this problem without the help of sufficient descriptions.

I was only able to check the syntax as I am a beginner and I don't know what to do in these situations. :P

```
@Composable
```

fun GreetingText(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
Text(
text = message
fontSize = 100.sp
textHeight = 116.sp
)
Text(
text = from
fontSize = 36.sp

```
)
```

}

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to change the input font size in TextField of Android Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72901072/9641046)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
@Composable
fun GreetingText(
    message: String,
    from: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Text(
        text = message,
        fontSize = 100.sp,
    )
    Text(
        text = from,
        fontSize = 36.sp
    )
}
```

I think you missed `,`. And `Text` does not have `textHeight` property, so please check what you need.

Good luck!